# Unable to run cron job that opens a terminal window

Tags: cron, gnome-terminal

I have a cron job that calls a script to run rsync and sync my files to an external drive every weekend. I had this working smoothly on Linux Mint 16 or 17. i need to show a terminal window to display the status to the user and also to ask them to turn the drive on

Then I installed Mint 19.1 and the script stopped executing. I can get the script to work if I run it without displaying a UI but I can't get it to run in a visible terminal.

I'm using this command in my crontab
The script I'm trying to run is test2.sh, the first one runs fine

```
    MAILTO=""
05 00 * * * env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus /mnt/Files/Software/Software\ Customizations/Linux/Scripts/rsync_backup_daily.sh
*/1 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && export XAUTHORITY=/home/vortex/.Xauthority && gnome-terminal -e "/mnt/Files/Software/Software\ Customizations/Linux/Scripts/test2.sh"
```

Running systemctl status cron gives me this

```
Jun 22 00:41:01 MK-PC CRON[5592]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user sam by (uid=0)
Jun 22 00:41:01 MK-PC CRON[5593]: (sam) CMD (export DISPLAY=:0 && export XAUTHORITY=/home/sam/.Xauthority && gnome-terminal -e "/mnt/Files/Software/Software\ Customizations/Linux/Scripts/test2.sh")
Jun 22 00:41:02 MK-PC dbus-daemon[5603]: [session uid=1000 pid=5601] AppArmor D-Bus mediation is enabled
Jun 22 00:41:05 MK-PC CRON[5592]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user sam
```

Answer (score 0):

crontab jobs are runned as root, [without terminal attached](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/325346/how-to-execute-the-command-in-cronjob-to-display-the-output-in-terminal).

But you can retrieve update in a terminal (dirty way, but it works).

```
*/1 * * * *   /mnt/Files/Software/Software\ Customizations/Linux/Scripts/test2.sh > /tmp/myscript.output
```

Then in a terminal:

```
gnome-terminal -e 'watch -n 60 cat /tmp/myscript.output'
```

Hope this help

**Edit:**

```
* *     * * *   root    export DISPLAY=:0.0 && xed /home/vi/test
```

You also need to allow connection to current X Server:

```
xhost local:root
```

The thing is that the last line isn't persistent, next reboot you need to input it again.

Comment: There are plenty of posts using export DISPLAY=:0 to display the output to a terminal

It used to work on my previous Linux install. I'm trying to understand what changed.

Also, I want the job to be interactive, hence just watching the output in terminal wouldn't work

Comment: After some search, found a solution :) we can use your export (xed is a graphical application).